# Three.JS skybox wont show up. Did I do something wrong with the dimensions

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, 3d, skybox

I use a small three.js scene in my project
I created a skybox but it wont show up.

But i made a small box and that one works perfectly.
Maybe i gave the camera wrong settings so it cant see the skybox.

Here is my full code:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 20000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
var div = document.getElementById("background");
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
div.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
camera.position.z = 5;

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

var skyboxMaterials =
[
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( 
        {map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("skybox/ft.png"),side: THREE.DoubleSide}
        ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( 
        {map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("skybox/bk.png"),side: THREE.DoubleSide}
        ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( 
        {map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("skybox/up.png"),side: THREE.DoubleSide}
        ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( 
        {map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("skybox/dn.png"),side: THREE.DoubleSide}
        ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( 
        {map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("skybox/rt.png"),side: THREE.DoubleSide}
        ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( 
        {map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("skybox/lf.png"),side: THREE.DoubleSide}
        )
];

var skyboxGeom = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 5000, 5000, 5000, 1, 1, 1 );
var skybox = new THREE.Mesh( skyboxGeom, skyboxMaterials );
scene.add( skybox );

var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 ); // soft white light
scene.add( light );

var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
};

animate();
```

Now the cube is showing in front of the camera and rotating
But i cant see the skybox.
I tried changing values on skybox and camera but nothing worked so I'm asking you now.

Answer (score 0):

The camera might not be seeing your sky box if it's facing outwards. Try setting `side:THREE.BackSide` to your array of skybox materials.

Ideally also, to make it behave like a real sky box, you might want to do something like this:

```
//provided this is the scene graph (same parent, otherwise you have to transform camera position)
scene.add(camera)
scene.add(skybox)

function animate(){

   skyBox.position.copy(camera.position)
   renderer.render()
}
```

This should remove all parallax. I'm not sure if it's best to draw the skybox before or after the scene, but either way you can do something like this:

```
skyBox.renderOrder = -1 || 1 //before or after
```